# Slicing array of struct in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog

Suppose there is a structure declared as:

```
typedef logic [7:0] Data;
typedef struct packed {
    logic valid;
    Data data;
} MyStruct;
```

An array of the struct is declared as:

```
MyStruct foo [8];
```

Is there a way other than using for loop to extract a field from all the array elements and form its own array/bit-vector?

In other words, I'm hoping to do something like this, which unfortunately doesn't seem to be valid SV syntax.

```
assign all_valid =  & foo[7:0].valid;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't slice an array like this in SystemVerilog, but because you are trying to do a reduction, there is a array manipulation method that you can use:

```
assign all_valid =  foo.and() with (item.valid);
```

See **Section 7.12.3 Array reduction methods** in the 1800-2012 LRM.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty neat! Too bad this isn't supported by Quartus.